# System of Linear Equations 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

A theater sold 160 children’s tickets and 90 adult tickets. If the theater made $1,600 from the sales of the tickets, what were the prices
of each ticket?

My set up is:

```
children   160   c   160c

adults      90   a    90a

Total      250       1600
```

First equation:
160 + 90 = 250

Second equation: 
160c + 90a = 1600

answer:

a = $8.00

c = $5.50

How to solve?  Is there enough information?

Comment: Just noting that like this, the first equation tells us nothing useful

Comment: To me it doesn't look like there's enough information though.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to give a definite answer because you have two variables and enough information for only one equation ($160c + 90a = 1600$). For example, $a$ could equal $c$, where $a$ is the price of adult tickets and $c$ is the price of children's tickets. You could find all possible answers by treating $a$ and $c$ as $y$ and $x$ and graph it as a line. All points on the line represent a possible answer to the problem as long as both $x$ and $y$ are greater than or equal to $0$ (bound the graph $x \geq 0$, $y\geq 0$).